# Factoring a Joint Density Function

Tags: probability-theory

Ross states that:

The continuous (discrete) random variables X and Y are independent iff their joint probability density (mass) function can be expressed as:

$$f_{xy}(x,y)=g(x)h(y)\quad -\infty<x<\infty, -\infty<y<\infty $$

Must g(x) and h(y) be the marginal densities of X and Y respectively, or can they be any arbitrary functions whose product is equal to the joint density function?

Comment: Actually, equality can fail for a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ with measure zero (for instance, a finite number of points, or a countable set, etc.), and if it's true for every other pair $(x,y)$ it still implies independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $f_{XY}(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ is a joint density function of $X$ and $Y$. Then the marginal distribution of $X$ has a density function
$$f_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} f_{XY}(x,y) dy=\int_{\mathbb R} g(x) h(y) dy=g(x)\int_{\mathbb R} h(y) dy.$$
Assuming also that $h$ is integrable over the reals and non-negative, we can call $k=\int_{\mathbb R} h(y) dy$, so that
$$f_X(x)=k\, g(x).$$
Then $g$ is a multiple of $f_X$ and the proportionality constant is $k>0$.

In the same way it is shown that $h$ is a multiple of $f_Y$.
And moreover, if $h$ is itself a density, that means that $k=1$ so $g$ is also a density and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not themselves the marginal densities (or pmf's in the discrete case), they are constant multiples of the marginal densities (or pmf's).